# Magento2: Vat Validation on checkout page?

Tags: magento2.3, vat, id

How can i validate VAT number on checkout page how it is validated on backend when setting store vat number?

Comment: There are ready made extensions out there that do this already swissuplabs.com/tax-vat-for-magento-2.html whilst I understand you want to write this yourself it's not a small task and your time is more valuable

Comment: @DominicXigen Well yeah i know that extension, but i need to write it myself.

Comment: @atniqi were you able to do so through code?